# Android JNI develop when i call (*env)->CallVoidMethod function result crash

Tags: java-native-interface

```
tag:adc5dcaf540a1541c2d41087c2b98004:54ef4c330a2e654b890dedc561fbe797
Exception:(9.10.0.2503)Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/EML-AL00/HWEML:9/HUAWEIEML-AL00/187C00R1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 27696, tid: 28121, name: spdy-0 >>> com.autonavi.minimap <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 00006dd9 r2 00000006 r3 00000008
r4 00006c30 r5 00006dd9 r6 ce3723fc r7 0000010c
r8 00000073 r9 d4f127dc sl ce37270c fp ce3726c8
ip 00000041 sp ce3723e8 lr f48e98dd pc f48e1602 cpsr 200f0030

backtrace:
#00 pc 0001d602 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+57)
#01 pc 0035f14b /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+950)
#02 pc 0000720b /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+578)
#03 pc 001b2227 /system/lib/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::AbortIfNoCheckJNI(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)+174)
#04 pc 00233c4f /system/lib/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::GetChecked(void*) const+274)
#05 pc 0022ff73 /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::DecodeGlobal(void*)+10)
#06 pc 00385c0d /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const+168)
#07 pc 00358f77 /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray::BuildArgArrayFromVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ObjPtr, std::__va_list)+82)
#08 pc 00359fc9 /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+300)
#09 pc 00271809 /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallVoidMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+492)
#10 pc 00004f43 /data/app/com.autonavi.minimap-Dkv8mcA_IvSPBVcGwBUYKQ==/lib/arm/libtnet-4.0.0.so
```

---

### PC 00004f43 is the function

(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, agent->thiz, agent->methodCustomControlFrameFail,
                               javaSession, userData, id, error);

system:  android 9

huawei/honor

```
--------------------------------------
Context as follow:
--------------------------------------
    if (env != NULL) {
        //callback java interface
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, agent->thiz, agent->methodCustomControlFrameFail,
                               javaSession, userData, id, error);
        checkJNIException(env);
        CJNICheckExp(env);
    }
```

Comment: The implementation of [GetChecjed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/indirect_reference_table-inl.h#36) shows several checks that can lead to an abort. The crash should come with a log message that specifies which assumption was violated.

Comment: Think's, I will add check, Is android 9  check more strict than before android version ？ it see like just appear in android 9 sometime

Comment: It sounds like you are relying on undefined behavior and Android 9 just happens to trigger it more often.